# Why Facebook Page Address does not get updated Using Graph API v19.0?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, restfb

I'm working with the Facebook Graph API v19.0 to update my Facebook Page's address details. According to the documentation, I can use a POST request to the /page_id endpoint with parameters I want to update, like the about section. However, when attempting to update location-related fields (e.g., address, city, zip), my request returns a {"success":true} response, but the page address doesn't update.

I'm using a Page access token with the necessary permissions and setting the Content-Type to application/json.

Could someone clarify how I can update a page's address using the Graph API v19.0? Also, is there a specific JSON structure or additional fields needed for the location update to be processed correctly?

Here's an example of my current JSON payload for reference:

```
{
  "emails": [
    "whatsoever@something.com"
  ],
  "website": "https://whatsoever.something.com",
  "location": {
    "zip": "the zipcode",
    "street": "the address",
    "latitude": 44.800671,
    "city_id": "1186314",
    "longitude": 10.3314355
  },
  "contact_address": {
    "zip": "the zipcode",
    "street1": "the address",
    "street2": "",
    "city_id": "1186314"
  }
}
```

I have also tried to add city_id field or contact_address, nothing changes.
The code I use in Java :

```
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/" + page_id; 

    // Create the main JSON object
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    jsonData.put("about", "Software company");
    jsonData.put("email", "Something");
    jsonData.put("website", "Something");

    // Create a nested JSON object for location
    JSONObject location = new JSONObject();;

    // Creating a nested location map to structure the JSON correctly
    location.put("city", city);
    location.put("country", country);
    location.put("latitude", latitude);
    location.put("longitude", longitude);
    location.put("street",  address);
    location.put("zip", zipCode);



     jsonData.put("location", location);
    jsonData.put("access_token", page_access_token);  

    // Prepare the HTTP request with the JSON content type
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonData.toString()))
            .build();

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    try {
        // Send the request and receive the response
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        
        // Process the response
        System.out.println("Response Status Code: " + response.statusCode());
        System.out.println("Response Body: " + response.body());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The response is:

[image]

But in my Facebook page I see no changes (Just the Address does not change).
Even if, it is possible to update the address using `restFB` I would be so thankful to know the code or any hint.

Comment: without further digging into it. "email" is not a valid field. There is 'emails' with an array of strings in the reference. Have you already tried to reduce the fields and check if for example updating website is working?

Comment: @Norbert: thanks fir the response, I simply made a mistake here, I can update everything including emails and website etc. the only problem is the address. I will fix payload in this question.

Comment: @Norbert, yes I have even tried to only change the location like {
  "location": {
    "zip": "43121",
    "street": "Via Repubblica 25",
    "latitude": 44.800671,
    "city_id": "1186314",
    "longitude": 10.3314355
  }
} no changes on the address is visible

Comment: With RestFB it looks like this. I tried the code and only changed the street. This worked for me. I think you have to check, what part of the JSON is the problem.
```DefaultFacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.LATEST);
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setCity("City");
        ...
        GraphResponse response = fbClient.publish("me", GraphResponse.class, Parameter.with("location", location));```